# Not going to masjid because of hostile people?

Tags: salat, masjid

Assalamu Alaikum Brothers in Islam,

Where i stay, there are only 2 masjids near by. 
Both of them are run/dominated by the same group of Muslim brothers. 
Because of the way that i pray (Rafa yadain and hands on chest), they are hostile towards me, and they sit and comment to others regarding my Salah while I'm IN prayer in quite an audible voice.

Also, I feel as if my every move is constantly watched by the them. The whole masjid just feel extremely hostile to me.

Whenever i start my Salah, i feel extremely distracted by thoughts and waswas of these people mostly because they are constantly coughing. (Intentionally to provoke or not i'm not sure) 
Instead of concentrating on Allah, my entire attention is towards them, and i feel quiet provoked and extremely anxious.

In such situations is it permissible for a muslim male to pray at home instead?

Please note : one of the masjid is 1.5kms away and the other 2.5kms away from my home.

Comment: Im speaking of fard congregational prayer

Comment: It is better to leave an act of Sunnah than missing Jama'ah. Raising your hands before and after Ruku' is Sunnah.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't see any hostility in what you describe. Many of these things can be cleared by a good and truthful conversation.